# Comparing two groups with big gap in sample sizes?

Tags: t-test

I have two groups which are about their departments in college (For example, group1=faculty of x, group2=faculty of y).

However, the size of the group1 is 12 and size of the group2 is 99. There is a big gap between the group size. My intention is to test their perceptions based on their departmen. Is it appropriate to compare them? I will use independent t-test.

Comment: Especially if the smaller group has the larger sample SD, then be sure to use a _Welch_ two-sample t test.

Comment: Thank you so much!